# Finding Firefox Default Profile Path in Docker Linux Container

Tags: linux, firefox, dockerfile, docker-container, firefox-profile

I have created a Dockerfile for a puppeteer project that installs firefox in a linux container. Firefox is successfully installed in the container and I mount a volume into this container but I'm unable to find the firefox default profile path in the container.

First, I build an image using the command "docker build -t newimage2 .", then I mount a volume into the container using this command in the terminal "docker run -it -v vol1:/shared-volume --name newcont3 newimage2". The volume vol1 is mounted into the newly created docker container newcont3 and firefox gets installed in the container. I need to locate the firefox default path in the container but I am unable to locate the firefox default profile path. This is my Dockerfile below.

```
FROM node:16.17.1
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y wget gnupg fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-freefont-ttf firefox-esr --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 5551
# Exec form
CMD ["npm", "start"]
#ENTRYPOINT [ "npm", "start" ] can choose either the entrypoint or the CMD
```

Comment: Why installing firefox at all? `npm i puppeteer` install chromium by default

Comment: I'm using puppeteer and puppeteer is not able to handle personal certification. Therefore, I'm using firefox as firefox is the only browser that can handle certificates, we can reuse saved certificates without any browser level notification or alert. Chrome gives alerts for each and every certificate but puppeteer is unable to handle those kind of requests.

Comment: You mean X509 certificate?

Comment: No, it's a custom certificate.